# Sampling parameters from the beta distribution with a given correlation

Tags: correlation, sampling, beta-distribution

Let a correlation matrix $\Sigma$ be given. I would like to sample from the n-dimensional multivariate beta distribution where each marginal distribution is known and the variables are correlated as prescribed by $\Sigma$. Is there a way to do this, preferably one that is not very expensive computationally?

There is a lot of info on how to solve similar problems for the normal distribution (see [link to Wikipedia with a well-known procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution), or [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120179/generating-data-with-a-given-sample-covariance-matrix) or [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of)) and there are some questions on how to do this for the special case of $n=2$ ([for example this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285142/how-to-generate-2-correlated-beta-random-variables)). But I cannot find information on this specific question here, neither on Google or SE.

Comment: There isn't a single multivariate beta, but any number of ways to make multivariate distributions with beta margins. Are you talking about a Dirichlet distribution or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b Maybe I'm misunderstanding the terminology here, but by the n-dimensional multivariate beta distribution, I just mean a vector $x$ of length $n$ in which each element is a random variable that follows the beta distribution. Is that inaccurate?

Comment: There's an infinity of distributions with Beta margins. Are you indifferent to what the joint distribution is as long as it has beta margins and you can get approximately the desired correlations?

Comment: Magnussen (2004) does this using a ratio of Gamma distributions.           

Magnussen, Steen. 2004. An algorithm for generating positively correlated Beta-distributed random variables with known marginal distributions and a specified correlation, *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, **46**, 397–406.