# Modeling a Correlated Bivariate Beta Distributions in PyMC3

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, beta-distribution, bivariate, pymc

My goal is to perform a bayesian A/B test of probabilities of success in two groups considering a hypothesis about non-zero covariance between those probabilities.

#### Bivariate beta distribution

I am trying to implement a bivariate beta distribution model as proposed by Barry C.Arnold, Hon Keung Tony Ng in ["Flexible bivariate beta distributions"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmva.2011.04.001) using PyMC3. The main formulae is denoted (1) in the article:

Bivariate random variable $(X, Y)$ is defined as a function of five Gamma distributed variables $U_i$ with scale parameters equal to 1:

$$U_i \sim Gamma(\alpha_i, 1)$$

$$X = \frac{U_1+U_3}{U_1+U_3+U_4+U_5}; Y = \frac{U_2+U_4}{U_2+U_3+U_4+U_5}$$

When constructed this way, random variables $(X, Y)$ are meant to present a (possibly) covariated pair of Beta random variables.

The marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are beta distributions with parameters $(\alpha_1+\alpha_3, \alpha_4+\alpha_5)$ and $(\alpha_2+\alpha_4, \alpha_3+\alpha_5)$, respectively.

#### Data

I have a small (generated) dataset containing daily numbers of trials (denoted `trials_a` and `trials_b`) and successes (denoted `successes_a` and `successes_b`) in two groups (a/b testing). Daily conversion rates are correlated and I'd like to take that fact into account while sampling from posterior beta distributions to obtain more relevant estimation of difference between conversion rates.

Also I have some prior knowledge about marginal betas, e.g. from analyzing data obtained before the start of a/b test. Let's consider `prior_alpha=20` and `prior_beta=4980` which are equal for both marginals.

The code in python for generating a dataset is as following:

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


DAYS = 30

# params for generating daily number of trials
TRIALS_MEAN = 5000
TRIALS_STD = 200**2
TRIALS_COV_FACTOR = 0.999

# prior knowledge about probability of success in both groups
PRIOR_ALPHA = 20
PRIOR_BETA = TRIALS_MEAN - PRIOR_ALPHA

# (unknown) probability of success in group A should be a little less than in prior
PROB_A_ALPHA = PRIOR_ALPHA - 1
PROB_A_BETA = TRIALS_MEAN - PROB_A_ALPHA

# (unknown) probability of success in group B should be a little more than in prior
PROB_B_ALPHA = PRIOR_ALPHA + 1
PROB_B_BETA = TRIALS_MEAN - PROB_B_ALPHA

# some value which allows covariance in probabilities via normal copula
BETAS_COPULA_COV_FACTOR = 0.5

np.random.seed(0)


def make_data():
    def make_trials():
        """Creates strongly correlated daily number of trials"""
        mvnorm = stats.multivariate_normal(
            mean=[TRIALS_MEAN, TRIALS_MEAN],
            cov=[[TRIALS_STD, TRIALS_COV_FACTOR*TRIALS_STD],
                 [TRIALS_COV_FACTOR*TRIALS_STD, TRIALS_STD]])
        return mvnorm.rvs(DAYS).astype(int)

    def make_probs():
        """Creates correlated daily probs of success using normal copula"""

        def covariate(rv1: stats.rv_continuous, rv2: stats.rv_continuous, cov_factor: float, n: int):
            def make_copula():
                mvnorm = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[0, 0], cov=[[1., cov_factor],
                                                                     [cov_factor, 1.]])
                # Generate random samples from multivariate normal with covariance
                x = mvnorm.rvs(n)
                return stats.norm.cdf(x=x)

            copula = make_copula()
            s1 = rv1.ppf(copula[:, 0])
            s2 = rv2.ppf(copula[:, 1])
            return np.vstack((s1, s2))

        beta_a = stats.beta(PROB_A_ALPHA, PROB_A_BETA)
        beta_b = stats.beta(PROB_B_ALPHA, PROB_B_BETA)
        return covariate(rv1=beta_a, rv2=beta_b, cov_factor=BETAS_COPULA_COV_FACTOR, n=DAYS).T

    trials = make_trials()
    probs = make_probs()
    # creates daily number of successes by sampling from binomial with corresponding number of trials
    # and prob of success

    successes = np.random.binomial(trials, probs)

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.hstack(
            (trials, probs, successes)
        ),
        columns=['trials_a', 'trials_b', 'prob_a', 'prob_b', 'successes_a', 'successes_b']
    )
    return df


df = make_data()
print(df.head())
# output:
#   trials_a  trials_b    prob_a    prob_b  successes_a  successes_b
#0    4645.0    4649.0  0.004429  0.004510         15.0         28.0  
#1    4794.0    4814.0  0.005251  0.003992         28.0         34.0  
#2    4630.0    4622.0  0.003775  0.003821         13.0         22.0  
#3    4810.0    4809.0  0.004845  0.005806         19.0         29.0  
#4    5018.0    5022.0  0.004427  0.004914         17.0         30.0
```

#### Model in theory

As mentioned above, I have some prior knowledge about the marginal distributions of betas:

$$X_{margin} = Y_{margin} = Beta(prior\_alpha, prior\_beta)$$

And we have their expressions in terms of $\alpha_i$ from the paper:

$$X_{margin} = Beta(\alpha_1+\alpha_3, \alpha_4+\alpha_5); Y_{margin} = Beta(\alpha_2+\alpha_4, \alpha_3+\alpha_5)$$

Unfortunately I don't know anything about covariance prior. Therefore my prior knowledge about $\alpha$s can be expressed like this (I am very unsure about correctness of these lines):

$$some\_latent\_var = Uniform(0.001, min(prior\_alpha, prior\_beta))$$

$$\alpha_3, \alpha_4 \sim some\_latent\_var$$

$$\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \sim prior\_alpha - some\_latent\_var$$

$$\alpha_5 \sim prior\_beta - some\_latent\_var$$

So then I incorporate the model mentioned above:

$$U_i \sim Gamma(\alpha_i, 1)$$

$$X = \frac{U_1+U_3}{U_1+U_3+U_4+U_5}; Y = \frac{U_2+U_4}{U_2+U_3+U_4+U_5}$$

And finally in test groups $a$ and $b$ I have $N$ ($N = 30$ in the example) independent and identically distributed binomial variables which generate daily number of succeses from daily number of trials (the latter are considered to be non-random). Probability of success in groups $a$ and $b$ follow the $X$ and $Y$ distributions respectively. Denoting day $d$'s and group $k$'s number of trials $trials_{k, d}$ and number of successes $successes_{k, d}$:

$$\forall d \in [1, N]: successes_{a, d} \sim Binomial(trials_{a, d}, X)$$

$$\forall d \in [1, N]: successes_{b, d} \sim Binomial(trials_{b, d}, Y)$$

I have both successes and trials in both groups in my dataset. Therefore I can construct this model in PyMC3 and sample from it to obtain posteriors for $X$ and $Y$.

#### Model in practice

I tried to follow the "Model in theory" as close as I could:

```py
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

with pm.Model() as model_five_params:
    # hyperparam's priors (just like in "Model in theory")
    some_latent_var = pm.Uniform('some_latent_var', lower=0.001, upper=min(PRIOR_ALPHA, PRIOR_BETA))
    alpha_3 = alpha_4 = some_latent_var
    alpha_1 = alpha_2 = PRIOR_ALPHA - some_latent_var
    alpha_5 = PRIOR_BETA - some_latent_var
    
    # five Gammas
    u_1 = pm.Gamma('u_1', alpha=alpha_1, beta=1)
    u_2 = pm.Gamma('u_2', alpha=alpha_2, beta=1)
    u_3 = pm.Gamma('u_3', alpha=alpha_3, beta=1)
    u_4 = pm.Gamma('u_4', alpha=alpha_4, beta=1)
    u_5 = pm.Gamma('u_5', alpha=alpha_5, beta=1)
    
    # construction of X and Y from Gammas
    # pm.Deterministic doesn't do anything special;
    # It just does the arithmetics and labels results
    # so that we can get traces for X and Y easily
    X = pm.Deterministic('X', (u_1+u_3)/(u_1+u_3+u_4+u_5))
    Y = pm.Deterministic('Y', (u_2+u_4)/(u_2+u_3+u_4+u_5))

    # I hoped this trick of stacking X and Y together would help
    # PyMC3 to understand that observations are linked too
    beta = tt.stack([X, Y])

    # Introduce the final step of Binomials to the model
    # and pass the observations to it
    # Numbers of trials and numbers of successes are passed in shapes (N, 2)
    obs = pm.Binomial(
        'obs',
        n=df[['trials_a', 'trials_b']].values,
        p=beta,
        observed=df[['successes_a', 'successes_b']].values
    )

with model_five_params:
    # sampling process of the model which results in a 'trace' object
    # 'trace' contains samples from posterior distributions of every
    # variable defined in model. We are especially interested in X and Y
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace_five_params = pm.sample(200000, tune=20000, step=step, init='advi')
```

#### Analyzing the results

The posterior traces of $X$ and $Y$ are very similar to beta posteriors obtained analytically as following:

$$\forall k, \forall d: fails_{k, d} = trials_{k, d} - successes_{k, d}$$
$$X = Beta(prior\_alpha + \sum_{d=1}^Nsuccesses_{a, d}, prior\_beta + \sum_{d=1}^Nfails_{a, d})$$
$$Y = Beta(prior\_alpha + \sum_{d=1}^Nsuccesses_{b, d}, prior\_beta + \sum_{d=1}^Nfails_{b, d})$$

```py
beta_a_exact = stats.beta(
    a=PRIOR_ALPHA + df['successes_a'].sum(),
    b=PRIOR_BETA + df['trials_a'].sum() - df['successes_a'].sum()
)
beta_b_exact = stats.beta(
    a=PRIOR_ALPHA + df['successes_b'].sum(),
    b=PRIOR_BETA + df['trials_b'].sum() - df['successes_b'].sum()
)
```

The fact that posterior traces of $X$ and $Y$ do match the analytical posteriors can be illustrated with a plot combaining the histograms of traces and PDFs of Beta distributions obtained analytically.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)

x_0 = np.linspace(beta_a_exact.ppf(0.00001), beta_a_exact.ppf(0.99999), 1000)
ax.plot(x_0, beta_a_exact.pdf(x_0), label='Analytical $X$')
ax.hist(trace_five_params.get_values('X', burn=50000), density=True, bins=50, alpha=0.5, label='Trace for $X$')

x_1 = np.linspace(beta_b_exact.ppf(0.00001), beta_b_exact.ppf(0.99999), 1000)
ax.plot(x_1, beta_b_exact.pdf(x_1), label='Analytical $Y$')
ax.hist(trace_five_params.get_values('Y', burn=50000), density=True, bins=50, alpha=0.5, label='Trace for $Y$')

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('$p$')
ax.set_ylabel('$f(p)$')

plt.show()
```

[image: trace vs analytical posteriors]

This results is a *somewhat* desired output because posterior traces were expected to match the analytical solutions for marginals.

But, unfortunately, the model doesn't show any correlation between two betas:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(
    trace_five_params.get_values('X', burn=50000),
    trace_five_params.get_values('Y', burn=50000),
    bins=50
)
ax.set_xlabel('$X$ trace')
ax.set_ylabel('$Y$ trace')
plt.show()
```

[image: correlation of traces]

**The expected output:** 2d histogram shows correlation between $X$ and $Y$ because daily probabilities of success in example dataframe are correlated and model was supposed to catch this correlation.

**What I got**: 2d histogram shows no correlation.

The questions are:

1. Is the theoretical model correct and should it actually covariate $X$ and $Y$?
2. If the answer is "yes" then how do I modify my PyMC3 model so it actually catches the correlation between conversion rates?

Comment: While a coding-related question, this clearly "requires statistical expertise" (per our [help/on-topic], so I am voting to reopen.

Comment: First, I'd like to note that the _program_ itself does not contain any bugs as it does not raise any exceptions. Second, I expect the answer to be something like "Introduce a latent variable bla-bla-bla..." which changes the statistical model, not only the program, and may be even language-agnostic.

Comment: Could you explain in words and/or mathematical expressions what your program is intended to do?  In particular, what does the function `pm.Deterministic` do?  I believe I know the answer based on researching [the documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/continuous.html#pymc3.distributions.continuous.Gamma): I am urging you to refer to it because that might expose the problem with the code.

Comment: @Valery It's *very* easy to write code that is syntactically correct (e.g. doesn't raise exceptions), but *does not do what you intended it to do*. As such, code is a very poor way of explaining to others what you're trying to achieve, since you may not correctly implement what you want but readers may be unlikely to infer the difference between what you write and what you seek to do. That you don't know the distinction between code that runs and code that is bug-free means it's even more critical than it usually is that you explain in detail what you're trying to do outside of your code.

Comment: On which see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug : "*A software bug is an error, flaw or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways.*" -- note that there's no mention of necessarily raising exceptions there; any result that is not what was intended would imply a bug.

Comment: Sure, I was wrong saying that code is bug-free because it doesn't raise exceptions. What I meant was that it doesn't raise exceptions and provides _somewhat_ desired output (see that marginal posteriors look like was expected). That means I didn't mess up shapes of data provided nor forgot some crucial step and so on. I was trying to catch the difference between this kind of bugs which make my question off-topic and a bug in model specification which is relevant for this site (I believe). While the Wikipedia's definition of bugs seems to make every question about statistical code off-topic.

Comment: Sure, later I will provide more information on the model I try to implement and I will link the code to that model specifically.

Comment: I've updated the question heavily and am looking forward to see it opened again because now it contains a lot of theoretical description of my problem.