# Impact of independence on parameters

Tags: machine-learning, probability, independence, joint-distribution, graphical-model

[image]

I am not getting why specifying a joint distribuion needs 2n parameters and then indepence reduces it to linear?

Comment: The simplest example ($n=2$) of specifying an arbitrary joint distribution of Boolean variables is discussed in detail at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284996.

Comment: @whuber my main issue is...what are parameters here...what do they look like...