The distribution of the sum of three dependent Bernoulli random variables, all with the same correlation
The problem is this:
$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{j\neq 1}^{n}X_{j}=z\right)=\text{??}$.
$X_{j} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p); j=2,3\ldots, n~$, $\text{Cor}(X_{i}, X_{j})=\rho~$,
$p=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\rho=\frac{7}{27}$.
$\mathbb{P}(X_{1}+X_{2}=z)=\text{?}$
$\mathbb{P}(X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}=z)=\text{?}$
$\mathbb{P}(X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}\ldots+ X_{n}=z)=\text{?}$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

While the correlation would be sufficient to determine the bivariate relationship between any pair of Bernoulli distributions (and hence the pmf of their sum), in general it does not suffice to determine the trivariate distribution. For example, imagine that $\rho=0$ and $p=\frac12$. While that would determine the distribution of $X+Y$ (and $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$), it doesn't determine the distribution of $X+Y+Z$.

There's a relevant example here of that situation where the variables are pairwise independent $\rho=0$, but the triple isn't, so we can see that you can get a variety of outcomes for the distribution of the sum.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284996 explains why this question is ill-posed.

You changed the question from $3$ variables to $n$ and specified precise values for $p$ and $\pho$ after you received upvoted answers.  I know this was encouraged by the question being closed by Xi'an, User1865345, Firebug, but it affects how this reads to later readers.  There will still be multiple distributions for the sums which satisfy the specific $p$ and $\rho$, though this will depend on the now unspecified $n$.

One obvious solution (out of many) is of course the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution

Glen_b's comments point to an example with $\rho=0$ and this is easily adapted for cases of $0 < \rho < 1$.   For example consider the three joint distributions below using $P$ for probabilities of one and $Q$ for another and $R$ for a third:
X  Y  Z  X+Y+Z       P    Q    R
0  0  0    0        0.2  0.3  0.1
0  0  1    1        0.1  0.0  0.2
0  1  0    1        0.1  0.0  0.2
1  0  0    1        0.1  0.0  0.2
0  1  1    2        0.1  0.2  0.0
1  0  1    2        0.1  0.2  0.0
1  1  0    2        0.1  0.2  0.0
1  1  1    3        0.2  0.1  0.3

and you will find $X,Y,Z \sim Bern(0.5)$ and pairwise $\rho=0.2$ using either $P$ or $Q$ or $R$ for the joint distributions, but the distributions of $X+Y+Z$ are very different between $P$ or $Q$ or $R$ even if the expectations are the same.  There are also more cases as linear combinations of $Q$ and $R$,  noting $P=\frac{Q+R}2$.

Let's try to make a more general statement.  Suppose you have a particular desired distribution for $W=X+Y+Z$ with $P(W=0)=p_0$, $P(W=1)=p_1$,  $P(W=2)=p_2$, $P(W=3)=p_3$ with $p_0+p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.
Then you can have $P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)=P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)=P(X=1,Y=0,Z=0)=\frac{p_1}{3}$ and $P(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)=P(X=1,Y=0,Z=1)=P(X=1,Y=1,Z=0)=\frac{p_2}{3}$, making $X,Y,Z$ all $Bern(\frac{p_1+2p_2+3p_3}{3})$ and $E[XY]=E[XZ]=E[YZ] = \frac{p_2}{3}+p_3$ from which you can find the pairwise correlation $\rho$.
But if instead you had used $q_0=p_0+\delta$, $q_1=p_1-3\delta$, $q_2=p_2+3\delta$,  $q_3=p_3-\delta$, for any $\delta$ (positive or negative) which keeps $q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3$ non-negative, then you would get the same Bernoulli distributions and the same pairwise correlation $\rho$.
So in general the Bernoulli distributions and the pairwise correlation cannot determine the distribution of $W=X+Y+Z$ (except in edge cases).

There's not enough information here to determine the distribution of $X+Y+Z.$
If $X,Y,Z$ are independent and $p=1/2,$ then the three correlations are $0,$ but this is not the only joint distribution of $X,Y,Z$ for which $p=1/2$ and the three correlations are $0.$
Suppose $X,Y$ are independent and
$$
Z\equiv X+Y \bmod2
$$
so that
$$
Z = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } (X,Y) = (0,0) \text{ or } (X,Y)=(1,1), \\ 1 & \text{if } (X,Y) = (1,0) \text{ or } (X,Y) = (0,1). \end{cases}
$$
If $p=1$ and the above holds, then all three correlations are $0,$ but the joint distribution is such that $\Pr(X+Y+Z=3) = 0.$ Whereas, if $X,Y,Z$ are independent and $p=0,$ then the correlations are all $0$ but $\Pr(X+Y+Z=3) = 1/8 \ne0.$
